# Use Responsive Image together with Flexbox

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I want to use the flexbox and the responsive image (the image with `scrset` and `sizes`). But the result seems horrible. The images have different height even if I used `flex-grow` to pull aligned, because the browser will load the different image with different sizes. I want the height of all images to be the same.

I found out `sizes` of images is hard to set if I use flexbox, it's quit unpredictable. Is there any way to solve this?

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/wjed91f5/2/) is the JSfiddle (Please resize the result window larger and the I used inline css for `flex-grow`)

Answer (score 0):

Set the image height property to:

```
height:100%;
```

And if you want your all images to be the same size set the same value for flex-grow.

```
flex-grow:1;
```